# Что означает присвоение null переменной типа Form?

Tags: c#

Вопрос по первой строчке. Я не совсем понимаю, как классу `Form` можно присвоить `null`. Смысл всего этого кода, чтобы вывести на панели другую форму. Объясните смысл строчки: `private Form activeForm = null;`

```
private Form activeForm = null;
private void panelbot(Form childForm)
{
    if (activeForm != null)
        activeForm.Close();
    activeForm = childForm;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panelFill.Controls.Add(childForm);
    panelFill.Tag = childForm;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: ``private Form activeForm = null`` означает, что переменная ``activeForm `` типа ``Form `` не ссылается ни на какой объект т.е. равна null. Вот тут можно почитать подробнее: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null

Comment: `как классу Form можно присвоить null` Классу ничего присвоить нельзя, можно присвоить значение переменной или полю.

Comment: Поможет чтение любой книги по С#

Answer (score 0):

Инстансу любого класса можно привоить null.

Это означает что даный инстанс не ссылается ни на одну область памяти.

В даном контексте - нету присовенной формы в даную переменную.

```
private Form activeForm = null; // нам не нужен предобьявленный инстанс
private void panelbot(Form childForm)
{
    // если форма была присвоена в переменную ранее
    // то закрываем ее
    if (activeForm != null)
        activeForm.Close(); 

    //и присваиваем новую
    activeForm = childForm;

    //а потом настраиваем ее и показываем
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panelFill.Controls.Add(childForm);
    panelFill.Tag = childForm;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
}
```